# how to reload a UIView with updated image programmaticaly

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I have a UIViewController which has a custom class of UIView.I am displaying an image on load of UIView.Ther is a UIButton in UIView,on clicking that button,it navigates to other UIViewController and from ther  a new image should be loaded in UIView.But in my app new image is loaded behind first image.How to refresh a UIView so that it only displays newly loaded image instead of overlapping of old image and new image.

Comment: How are you putting your image in the view? In an imageView? As the background color of the view? Show your code.

Comment: You can't put image for UIView like a UIImageView if you want to set image for you UIView set: self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];

Comment: I am putting image in UIImageview.